# How to test multi databases with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is a rails project. I want to use rspec to test multi operation with different databases.
This project name is app1. The test database is test_database1. I want to use another database in another project.
That project name is app2. The test database is test_database2.
I have tried to add the database2 create_table schema to app1 project. And I used factory_girl to generate test data use 
`factory :product, :class => App2::Product do`. However, when I run the rspec test, it showed me:

```
Failure/Error: let(:app2_products) { create(:product) }

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  Mysql2::Error: Table 'app2_test.products' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `products`
# ./spec/my_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/my_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# Mysql2::Error:
#   Table 'app2_test.products' doesn't exist
#   ./spec/my_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How to create database2 of app2 in app1 when using spec?

---

### Edit1

I added app2's test database in config/database.yml:

```
app2_test:
  <<: *app2_default
  database: app2_test
```

I also added create table schema about app2 to app1's db/schema.rb

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
end
```

But the result was the same.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `config/database.yml` and `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: @cenouro Yes, after I add the app2's test database in config/database.yml and tables in db/schema.rb, the result was the same. I will add that information in the question.

Comment: `schema.rb` should be a snapshot of your database definition after the migrations have run. In addition to modifinyg the file, you probably will have to run `rake db:schema:load` to apply the changes. Be ware that this is not recommended and will erase data on your databases.

Comment: @cenouro Thank you for your answer. I want to know if it is possible to do that use rspec and the addition schemas in the schema.rb. If I use Jenkins to do CI, I can do nothing such as `rake db:schema:load`.

Comment: It may be possible, but I think it will not be something productive. Your system(s) seems overly complex. Try redesigning them to be easy to test. Even if you decide to separete them in multiple services, you can test each one in isolation.

Comment: @cenouro Thank you very much. I run this in app2: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`. Then I can test in app1.